# PHP executes sql inside a false condition of IF statement with $_POST

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Please help with this difficult to understand bug: php always execute sql update inside IF with $_POST in condition.

When condition is false: the code i) not executes the echo command, but ii) it still executes the sql command

```
if ($_POST["scanned_set"] != "saved") {    
    try {
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=abc", $username, $password);
        // set the PDO error mode to exception
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        echo "Connected successfully";    

        // Update

        $sql = "UPDATE `id_scan` SET `scan_count` = 10 WHERE `id_scan`.`id` = 1";

        // use exec() because no results are returned
        $conn->exec($sql);        
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }

    $conn = null; 
}
```

and the strange thing is that, if I try the iF condition with "IF (1 ==2)" then code works well. In other words, it does not execute the sql.

**The full code**

```
<html>
<body> 

<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "reviinve_vchain";
$password = "";

var_dump($_POST["scanned_set"]);

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=reviinve_vchain", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    echo "Connected successfully"; 

    // Retrieve data from db
    $sql = "SELECT *  FROM `id_scan` WHERE `id` = 1";

        foreach ($conn->query($sql) as $row) {
        echo "print scan number after retrieving statement ".$row['scan_count'] . "\t";
        // print $row['color'] . "\t";

        $count_update = $row['scan_count'] + 1;     
        }        
}
    catch(PDOException $e){
        echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }

    $conn = null;

if ($_POST["scanned_set"] != "saved") {
    try {
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=reviinve_vchain", $username, $password);
        // set the PDO error mode to exception
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        echo "Connected successfully"; 

        // Update count number to db

        echo 'new count number' . $count_update;     

        $sql = "UPDATE `id_scan` SET `scan_count` = $count_update WHERE `id_scan`.`id` = 1";

        // use exec() because no results are returned
        $conn->exec($sql);
    }
    catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
    $conn = null; 
}

?> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `var_dump($_POST);` What's the output?

Comment: your condition might be true, try sending a proper POST variable and verify it using == (much easier); and of course Jon's suggestion.

Comment: @JonStirling I don't see a column with that name

Comment: _"When condition is false: the code i) not executes the echo command, but ii) it still executes the sql command"_ <- I don't buy this at all. How are you verifying this observation?

Comment: Sounds like you have the same SQL somewhere else in your script that's getting executed, and you don't realize it.

Comment: @JonStirling: the type of that $_POST is string, and its value is "saved". I of course have a correct table, because i go directly to that table in database to see it is updated !

Comment: @dossy: i did think about the situation you have mentioned. So i try to comment the line that execute the sql, then the bug disappeared ! So, it is not the same sql somewhere else execute that script to the database.

Comment: @ThongTran is the code you shared with us literally the exact same code that's in your program, or did you remove lines to create this example?  The code, as you've provided to us, cannot possibly execute the SQL statement and NOT echo the string `"Connected successfully"` so if you're seeing the SQL being executed but that line not being echoed, then there must be other code involved that we're not seeing.

Comment: @dossy yes, i removed some very basic code lines like database info etc. for you to easy to read

Comment: Could you include everything that's in your actual code that's inside the `if` statement?  If you want to mask out passwords you can change the value of the strings in the assignment, but there's something missing that would explain the behavior that you removed.

Comment: this time I even try to spit the code, because I think two sql statements may conflict if I don't release memory. But it still does not work. The full code is below

Comment: @dossy i attached the full code

Comment: Okay, so when you make an HTTP POST request to this PHP, and pass the POST form data for key `scanned_set` set to `saved`, you don't get the second `Connected successfully` in the output, nor  `new count number#`, but the `UPDATE` SQL statement is being executed?  There's literally no way for that to happen given the code you provided.

Comment: I wonder if you have output buffering turned on at some point, which is causing the `echo`'ed statements to not get written to the output buffer, but everything inside the `if` is being executed, including the SQL statement.

Comment: @dossy i) this is the only code that interacts with my database, so I don't have any output buffering ii) remind: if I change the condition to "IF (1 == 2)" then the bug disappear -> something wrong with the $_POST iii) for more info: the value ("saved") transferred to server is the value I retrieve from local database of client's browser

Comment: I think `if ($_POST["scanned_set"] != "saved") {` is your mistake - that `if` will always be `true` _unless_ `$_POST['scanned_set'] == 'saved'` ... when you change `if (1 == 2)` that is the same as `if (false)` ... but your `if ($_POST["scanned_set"] != "saved")` is basically `if (true)` ...

Comment: then how do you explain why it only executes the sql, not the echo statement ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try scrubbing your request variable first:

```
$do_update = !(trim(strtolower($_REQUEST["scanned_set"])) == "saved")

if ($do_update) {    
    try {
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=abc", $username, $password);
        // set the PDO error mode to exception
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        echo "Connected successfully";    

        // Update

        $sql = "UPDATE `id_scan` SET `scan_count` = 10 WHERE `id_scan`.`id` = 1";

        // use exec() because no results are returned
        $conn->exec($sql);        
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }

    $conn = null; 
}
```

Comment: I've tried your solution, but unfortunately it did not work !